# Keylogging virtual machine from host

Tags: virtualization, keyloggers

Can a keylogger in a host machine capture keystrokes in virtual OS?

I'd like to get into cryptocurrencies but I don't know if my machine (mac) is secure. So I thought I could create a VM for it but I guess its pointless if the host machine is compromised. Anyone knows what I should do

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. If you don't trust a bare-metal host, you can't trust any VMs running in it either.

Comment: so you have no solution

Comment: @user277849 Here's a solution: buy another physical machine that you do trust.

Comment: Awesome, can you like give me $500 so I can buy another physical machine?